# Vue CLI 3.0 - azure deploy

Tags: azure, vue.js

I want to deploy my app build in vue which use CLI 3.0.

My package.json:

```
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "postinstall": "npm run build",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
    "test:unit": "vue-cli-service test:unit",
    "test:e2e": "vue-cli-service test:e2e"
  }
```

I added `"@vue/cli": "^3.0.0-rc.3"` to devDependencies, but is don't see any changes.

Azure deploy result:

```
> npm run vue-cli-service build
npm ERR! missing script: vue-cli-service
```

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Me too, any solution? Struggling to get VUE CLI working on Azure

Comment: You do not need a `postinstall` script, `npm run build` already runs with the `build` script. Also what is the root directory you are using for your deployed files? It should be the `dist` folder, webpack creates with all deployable files after `npm run build` finishes.

Answer (score 4):

I havent used azure yet, but try only with

```
npm run build
```

instead of

```
npm run vue-cli-service build
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have a build pipeline that struggles with the message you have given.

I think what you are missing is a simple

```
npm install
```

After the install you are able to run

```
npm run build
```

Without the `npm install` before, threre is no `vue-cli-service` npm can find to build the application. I build my own vue-cli 3.0 app this way an deploy to azure like this from an Azure DevOps build pipeline.

or an other possibility is that you are missing another dependency. Add `"@vue/cli-service": "^3.0.1"` to your devDependencies. And as Daniel Gonzalez pointed out in the comments, there is no need for a `postinstall` script.

Answer (score 1):

I have succeed building Vue with Vue CLI 3 in Azure.

---

Sharing my build file here

Azure pipeline YAML script

```
resources:
- repo: self

trigger: ['staging']

pool:
  vmImage: 'Ubuntu 16.04'

steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  displayName: 'Use Node 10.x'
  inputs:
    versionSpec: 10.x

- script: |
    npm install
    npm run build-staging
  displayName: 'npm install and build'
  env:
    NODE_ENV: staging

- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  displayName: Archive
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: '$(build.sourcesDirectory)/dist'
    includeRootFolder: false
    archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.SourceVersion)_$(Build.BuildId).zip'


- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact: build'
  inputs:
    ArtifactName: build
```

package.json

```
...
 "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve --port 9001",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "build-staging": "NODE_ENV=production vue-cli-service build --mode staging",
    "build-production": "NODE_ENV=production vue-cli-service build --mode production",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
...
```

Comment: This does not work, I have rtried the same package.json and YAML

Answer (score 0):

Only way I have found to host Vue-CLI build files in Azure is this:

1. Create a StorageV2 in Azure. Make this a static website (under settings). Make index.html the index document name.
2. Run: npm run build
3. Install Azure Storage explorer
4. Open the new storage you created in step 1 in Azure Storage Explorer, go to Blob Containers, $web
5. Copy the build files from the ./dist folder to the $web folder.
6. Open a web browser, enter the endpoint URL.